# Alignment issue while creating vertical stepper html css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple vertical stepper component with html & css. And trying to design like [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#vertical-steppers). I strucked in the css part some alignment issues are coming.

CSS

```
.steps-container .step::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  right: 4px;
  top: 2px;
}

.steps-container .step.active::before {
  background-color: green;
}

.step-vertical {
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
      <div class="steps-container">
        <span class="step inactive">1</span>
        <div class="step-vertical">
          <div>
            <h5 class="text-grey">label text 1</h5>
            <button>Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="steps-container">
        <span class="step active">2</span>
        <div class="step-vertical">
          <div>
            <h5 class="text-grey">label text 2</h5>
            <button>Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image].

From the output i want the numbers 1 and 2 inside the circle and label text should align next to the circle. I don't know how to achieve this. Ur suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this how you want it? added the `:before` css to `span` added `display: inline-block;` to `.step-vertical` to bring it next to the span.

```css
.steps-container .step {
      display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    /* width: 20px; */
    /* height: 20px; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
    top: 2px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.steps-container .step.active::before {
  background-color: green;
}

.step-vertical {
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
height:200px
}

h5{margin-top: 5px;
display: inline-block;}

button{
  display:block
}

.ml-2{
  margin-left:10px
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="steps-container">
      <span class="step inactive">1</span>
      <h5 class="text-grey">label text 1</h5>
      <div class="step-vertical"> 
         <div>
           <textarea class="ml-2" name="" id=""     cols="30" rows="10">           
           </textarea>
           <button class="ml-2">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>       
  </div>
   <div class="steps-container">
      <span class="step inactive">2</span>
      <h5 class="text-grey">label text 2</h5>
      <div class="step-vertical"> 
         <div>
           <textarea class="ml-2" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">            </textarea>
           <button class="ml-2">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but the border line needs to below the circle like it was show in the link.

Comment: You can even place html elements where ever you want. But needs to achieve the result.

Comment: thanks @Xenio i will update if any issues happens with further development. if it is possible you can help me.